# Is "... the concept builds on the ..." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> "The **concept builds on the** principles of the money measurement concept."

Or should it be:

> "The concept is built on the principles of the money measurement concept."

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: It's fine either way. In the active sense, the "concept' has a life of its own, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that both of these are correct grammatically, but convey similar ideas instead of truly the same idea.

- The first seems to indicate that *the concept* is built so as to be an improvement or addition to the money measurement concept.
- The second would instead seem to indicate that *the concept* is a distinct idea that uses the money measurement concept as its foundational support.

Though with additional context surrounding either, this trivial difference likely would evaporate. That being said, both are indeed grammatically correct.

If you're unsure about the preposition usage of "on", here's a handy guide that may help solidify your confidence when using them: http://www.talkenglish.com/grammar/prepositions-on-at-in.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The meanings are slightly different.

In math, one concept *builds on* another.  You can imagine a tower of bricks, gradually getting built up taller and taller.

In your second sentence, though, there is only one layer getting added.  The bottom layer is the money measurement concept, and the new (unnamed) concept is the second layer.  That's it -- no additional levels, no tall tower.